# Assign results of globbing to a variable in Bash

Tags: bash, glob

My colleague, Ryan, came to me with a bug in his Bash script, and I identified the problem with this test:

```
$ mkdir ryan
$ mkdir ryan/smells-bad
$ FOO=ryan/smells-*
$ echo $FOO
ryan/smells-bad
$ touch $FOO/rotten_eggs
touch: cannot touch `ryan/smells-*/rotten_eggs': No such file or directory
```

From this I infer that the globbing happens during the echo command, not when the variable FOO is created.

We have a couple of workarounds, in descending order of ungracefulness:

```
touch `echo $FOO`/rotten_eggs
```

Or:

```
pushd
cd $FOO
touch rotten_eggs
popd
```

But neither is satisfying. Am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is that the glob will only expand if the file "rotten_eggs" exists, because it is included in the glob pattern. You should use an array.

```
FOO=( ryan/smells-* )
touch "${FOO[@]/%//rotten_eggs}"
```

The FOO array contains everything matched by the glob. The expansion using % appends /rotten_eggs to each element.

Comment: Thanks, this explains it nicely.

Comment: That is not the problem at all. 
The problem is that  bash assigns the glob to the variable before expansion. Even if the file existed, a glob would be assigned to the variable, not a file name; and that glob would be expanded on use

Comment: @SamLiddicott The OP's example would have worked if "rotten_eggs" existed, so it was more or less the problem. The time the glob is expanded is not relevant in the OP's short example.

Comment: @jordanm but is directly relevant to the question as asked and the title. Indeed the globbing happened in the echo. I'l add a an answer rather then argue it, because your point is good and your answer is useful.

Comment: @SamLiddicott was very right, but maybe even in his full answer not clear enough. In variable assignment `name=[value]`, value undergoes tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal, BUT NOT path expansion (globbing etc.). Try `FOO=ryan/smells-*; echo "$FOO"; echo $FOO;` to see what realy is assigned to Question's FOO.

Answer (score 7):

Consider

```
for dir in $FOO; do
    touch "$dir/rotten_eggs"
done
```

Note that this will `touch` multiple files if the glob pattern matches more than one pathname.

Comment: This will work, but it requires that touch runs multiple times, rather than once.

Answer (score 7):

The code as intended with the result of the glob assigned to the variable would be like this:

```
$ mkdir ryan
$ mkdir ryan/smells-bad
$ FOO=(ryan/smells-*)
$ echo "${FOO[@]}"
ryan/smells-bad
$ echo "$FOO"
ryan/smells-bad
$ touch "$FOO/rotten_eggs"
$ ls -l "$FOO"
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryan ryan 0 Mar  1 11:17 rotten_eggs
```

`$FOO` is actually an array here, but $FOO also works to get the first element of the array.

but, see how the glob can match more than one file (hence the array is a good idea)

```
$ mkdir ryan/clean
$ FOO=(ryan/*)
$ echo "$FOO"
ryan/clean
$ echo "${FOO[@]}"
ryan/clean ryan/smells-bad
```

In these cases the results of the glob is assigned to the variable as desired, rather than the variable being expanded as a glob at point of use.

Of course this means that the variable should really always be used in double quotation marks `"..."` otherwise if the filename itself (the glob expansion) also had a `*` in it, it would glob again.

e.g.

```
$ touch ryan/'*ea*'
$ FOO=(ryan/*ea*)
$ echo "${FOO[@]}"
ryan/clean ryan/*ea*
$ echo ${FOO[@]}
ryan/clean ryan/clean ryan/*ea*
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
for FOO in ryan/smells-*; do
  touch "$FOO"/rotten_eggs
done
```

This way `$FOO` contains the actual directory name, not the glob pattern. If there's more than one match, though, it will only contain the last one after the loop, so the array solution might be better for that case.